# Pandas subplot date ticks appear unevenly spaced with irregular time series

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I created this example after seeing the issue multiple times. This helped me realize that the problem comes when plotting the time series of a data frame with irregularly-spaced samples. The example below illustrate the issue.

1. I created two random time series with equally-spaced timestamps. Asking pandas to show it within different subplots works fine and provides correct date ticks.
2. I randomly dropped some samples and showed the time series in another set of subplots. This time, the minor ticks appear at random positions.

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# Create dataframe
time = pd.date_range("2007-04", "2019-03", freq="M")
data = np.random.rand(len(time), 2)
df = pd.DataFrame(data=data, index=time)

# Show with equally-spaced samples (case 1)
df.plot(subplots=True)

# Show with unevenly-spaced samples (case 2)
df = df.sample(frac=0.8, random_state=200)
df.plot(subplots=True)
```

**Case 1: evenly-sampled time series**

[image: pandas-subplots-evenly-sampled-correct-dateticks]

**Case 2: unevenly-sampled time series**

[image: pandas-subplots-unevenly-sampled-wrong-dateticks]

I also tried to include the following lines without success.

```py
dateticks = mdates.AutoDateLocator()
dateticklabels = mdates.ConciseDateFormatter(dateticks)
ax[-1].xaxis.set_major_locator(dateticks)
ax[-1].xaxis.set_major_formatter(dateticklabels)
```

So the questions are: would anyone know if there is a plan to fix this issue and if any solution would help solve it meanwhile?

### Note

I am using `pandas 1.4.1` with `matplotlib 3.5.1` and latest macOS version.

### Edit

Issue opened on GitHub: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/46961

Comment: When I retrieve the information for each data frame, `df.info()` I find that the index for the randomly sampled data frame has not changed. The sampled data is drawn on top of it. I assume this is what is causing the graph ticks to be out of sync.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I quite don't understand: `df.info()` returns a different index for each data frame on my side. Plus, what should I do to get the correct date ticks anyway?

Comment: Try this: `df = pd.DataFrame(data=data, index=time);df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)
df.sort_index(ascending=True, inplace=True);df.info();df.plot(subplots=True);df1 = df.sample(frac=0.8, random_state=200);df1.sort_index(ascending=True, inplace=True);df1.info();df1.plot(subplots=True)`

Comment: Thanks again. I just tried your suggestion, and it still does not work. The problem also arises with sorted uneven samples.